# How can I obtain Med Monster Bones?

Tags: monster-hunter-freedom-unite

How can I obtain Med Monster Bones from gathering quests at "level" Elder** ?

I need one of those things to improve my dual blades and I can't get one carving monsters. I've read that the elder lady should give them to you as a reward but from which quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the faster way is to kill Apceros monsters.

http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_Bone%2B#Monster_Bone.2B